# HiveOnSpark Performance tuning:why INSTR has much better performance than LIKE?

Tags: performance, hql

```
with t1 AS(
    SELECT
        date,
        request_id,
        maskdid,
        query
    FROM t_origin
),
SELECT 
    t2.query_like as `Query词`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT request_id) AS pv,   
    COUNT(DISTINCT maskdid) AS uv
FROM t1
JOIN tmp_query t2 
ON INSTR(t1.query, t2.query_keyword) > 0
GROUP by 1
```

```
with t1 AS(
    SELECT
        date,
        request_id,
        maskdid,
        query
    FROM t_origin
),
SELECT 
    t2.query_like as `Query词`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT request_id) AS pv,   
    COUNT(DISTINCT maskdid) AS uv
FROM t1
JOIN tmp_query t2 
ON t1.query LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.query_like, '%')
GROUP by 1
```

My HQL has a inner join to select the query row that match a particular keyword,and finnally count the appearance number of each keyword.I found that INSTR run for 4mins,much better than LIKE,whith run for 112mins.I want to know the reason,why?